# How to get information from an unknown format file

Tags: file, encryption

I have this file which is simply called "KEY", no extension. It is used by a software that runs on MS-DOS, a very old one. I suspect this program uses that to store data, like the login password and other information.

My problem is that its an ancient software, there is no way to find its creator and there is a parameter from that file that I need to change (if it indeed holds that information). But when I open it with a notepad I see this:

> ÜxÀYíÆÄÁÌsÎEÚ
>
> ¤gÄ[÷Á×
>
> ·
>
> ¤d×Q¤åÓÒÜs
>
> Äeè
>
> ¤|ÀRëÖÒÁÌ
>
> ¾•
>
> ¤ ö[ðÐ    Å€ÌyœHæ Õ_èÔÄÁ
>
> ¿
>
> É
>
> ¶
>
> ¤c÷o
>
> ³
>
> ¤ àNöÚ
>
> ³
>
> ¤c×]¤„F›žˆsÚB§ …¶•Kˆ€Çr
>
> ¶
>
> ¤ æKíÁ
>
> µ•´‚V€—œ(
>
> ÜzÄM÷Â    ÄÄõ
>
> ïEÂ_
>
> äCÀLöÐ
>
> äEËJöÚ
>
> ÜgÀP÷ÔÓÓõ
>
> ÃOÕ_öÁÛÅÆhÓ
>
> ÎDÂLáÆ–ÓÝ<ÿHæ\À
>
> *iÉ_òÐFÓÒÚ¾ÒAæ
>
> ÉXÊàÐFÄÅÏuÏPõKÁQöÔ
>
> ÂLÀ]ðÜÙŽ’
>
> ÓK×TáÁÅŽ’
>
> ÄBÀOñÐ˜Ž’
>
> ÄX'ZíÁ    ˜Ž’
>
> 3 ìPâÚÛÁËuÓJ§é
>
> ¤•
>
> 3 ñQðÔ ÓÓˆß
>
> 3 ëKáÃ    –ÖÉpÓV§é
>
> § …úú
>
> §Tñ_æÙÅ
>
> §Tæ_êÖÚÁ
>
> §TñLåÛÛÉÜuÎ
>
> ¶•
>
> ±•
>
> Û]ÌPàÚÅüËsÑIæDÁbéÓ…Ê2Ù\â

How can I decrypt this to get the information this file has?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have the software that processes it then you have a problem of reverse engineering.

Comment: I edited the question to simplify it. Could it please be reopened? Thank you @JamesKPolk

Comment: It should not be reopened. It is not a programming question and is still too broad. Please review [what questions can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok. Thank you James

Answer (score 1):

You can try TrIDNet, it will try to identify the file type based on known types.

http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html

Comment: Tried that, no results unfortunately.